# How to resolve the error like ‘atos cannot load symbols for the file APP for architecture armv7’?

Tags: ios, iphone, archive, symbolicatecrash

I tried to symbolicate the crash report.I put the **dsym** and **app** files put in a folder.Then I moved to this path via terminal.The I tried the following command in my terminal.

MacMini1$ **atos -arch armv7 -o APP  0x2b000**

But I got the error like **atos cannot load symbols for the file APP  for architecture armv7.**
Please help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: The linked post shows how atos is supposed to be used. You are missing the binary load address and should use the symbol file instead of the app binary, as normally app binaries have symbols stripped and if not only a subset of the information available in the symbol file